# How do I change this Greasemonkey script to work on a different page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, visited

I tried the script from [How can I detect visited and unvisited links on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290959/how-can-i-detect-visited-and-unvisited-links-on-a-page), and it works on the test page, but not on mine.

The answer, there, said that I need to change `SelectorStr`, but to what?
How do I check which are my options. I tried to search for `ui.topicList` and `a.topicTItle` but couldn't find anything on these values.

Edit (from a comment below):
I found this HTML in the page source:

```
<td class="plist"> 
    <a target="_top" href="/smartphones/clik-where-suppose.html" target="_self" ...
```

But, if set `SelectorStr` to `td.plist a._top`, It's still not working.

Comment: `selectorStr` will depend on the HTML in your page. Can you post the HTML youhave.

Comment: taurosolt, If you read that answer, it says that `selectorStr` has to be tuned as well as the `@include` directives, etc.  To help you do that, we **MUST** see the page or a file-save of it at http://pastebin.com/.  Edit your question to include this information.  Also, the HTML snippet from your comment does not look right.  It has 2 `target` attributes, for example. (But you might try `selectorStr = "td.plist a`.)

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried the code but i guess you have to put a Selector String there. In the example two things are used. The first is an unordered list with the class name topicList and the second are links with the class topicTitle.

So if you want to apply that code with that SelectorStr your html should look something like this:

```
<ul class="topicList">
      <li><a class="topicTitle" href="#">listitem 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="topicTitle" href="#">listitem 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="topicTitle" href="#">listitem 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, I found this code in source

</td><td class="plist">
                            <a target="_top" href="/smartphones/clik-where-suppose.html" target="_self"

if I put

td.plist a._top as SelectorStr

It's still not working. Can you please help. Thank you very much and sorry for bothering. I know that you are not paid for this, but I will likely donate to paypal.

Comment: edgarpetrauskas, it turns out that this is a Greasemonkey question.  The OP has no control over the target page source, sent by the server.