# Finding if a link has visited with jquery/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to find if a user has visited a link before moving on to the next page. I am trying to force them to proof a final PDF they have generated. If the link was not visited I need an alert box, if it was obviously false.

From what I can tell I will probably need both Jquery and PHP to do this. Has anyone ever ran into this issue before with results?

Comment: you can't do this in `PHP` , `CSS` and `jQuery` can do ,what you have tried so far ?

Comment: look here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290959/how-can-i-detect-visited-and-unvisited-links-on-a-page][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290959/how-can-i-detect-visited-and-unvisited-links-on-a-page

Answer (score 0):

Why not set a global js variable with a value? If they value doesn't match when 'next' is clicked then show the alert.

Shouldn't need PHP for this.

M