# change div style when href link is visited

Tags: html, css

I currently have a html file that contain such div:

```css
div.myClass:visited {
  background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="myClass" href="link">
</div>
```

What I am trying to do here is to have div direct to the given link and if the link is visited already, div background-color changes to red. The link does work fine, however changing the background color when the link is visited does not work. Is there a way to change the background color of div that contains a visited link? Thank you!

Comment: `div` elements do not have a `href` attribute. Why don’t you just use an `a` element, if you want to link somewhere? Everything else does just not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript to replace innerHTML

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function ReplaceContentInContainer(id, content) {
    var container = document.getElementById(id);
    container.innerHTML = content;
} </script>

<div id="example1div" style="border-style:solid;padding:10px; text-align:center;">
I will be replaced when you click.
</div>
<a href="javascript:ReplaceContentInContainer('example1div','Whew! You clicked!')">Click me to replace the content in the container.</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<a/>` instead of `div` and style it like `div` by giving it `display:block;` and `width` and `height`

for example:

```
<a class="myClass" href="http://www.lego.com/en-us/"></a>
```

CSS:

```
 .myClass {
     background-color: blue;
     width:200px;
     height:200px;
     display:block;
 }

.myClass:visited {
     background-color: red;
 }

.myClass:hover{
     background-color: green;
}
```

### [View on CodePin](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGwqZY)

Also look at :

[How can I detect visited and unvisited links on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7291538/1959631)

[Privacy and the :visited selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector)