# How can I get Greasemonkey to highlight visited image links?

Tags: javascript, html, css, greasemonkey

I use a site that displays various image links, but which gives no visual indicator as to which links I've already visited.

How can Greasemonkey tweak the links so that I can see, at a glance which links I've visited?

For example, given links like:

```
<a href="/056"> <img src="pic_A.png"> </a>
<a href="/138"> <img src="pic_1.png"> </a>
<a href="/144"> <img src="pic_B.png"> </a>
<a href="/150"> <img src="pic_2.png"> </a>
<a href="/153"> <img src="pic_C.png"> </a>
<!-- etc. -->
```

Can Greasemonkey indicate which ones have been visited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Greasemonkey can do this by using [GM_addStyle()](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_addStyle) to style `a:visited img` links.

But there is a caveat:
[**`:visited` CSS will only accept color rules.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)  This is for security reasons; see the previous link.

Here's one approach:

1. Add a border to all relevant image links.
2. Then `:visited` CSS can be used to change the border color of visited links.
   IMPORTANT:   `:visited` can't be used to add a border where one does not already exist.
3. This does outline all images, but there is currently no other way.  JavaScript cannot detect visited links; only CSS can. (This is the whole point of the security changes.)

A Complete Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script, that does that, looks like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Stylize visited image links
// @include  https://fiddle.jshell.net/BrockA/40dc7m31/*
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
GM_addStyle ( "                                 \
    a img {                                     \
        border: 5px solid blue !important;      \
        background: lightblue  !important;      \
    }                                           \
    a:visited img {                             \
        border: 5px solid purple !important;    \
        background: purple !important;          \
    }                                           \
" );
```

**You can test it on [this handy jsFiddle page.](https://jsfiddle.net/BrockA/40dc7m31/)**

- Without the script, the image-links look like this:
  [image: before]
- After the script, the visited links are outlined in purple:
  [image: after]

---

Notes:

1. The [Stylish add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) can also make this kind of CSS-only change.
2. Related question: [How can I detect visited and unvisited links on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290959/how-can-i-detect-visited-and-unvisited-links-on-a-page)

Comment: This works, thanks. I assume there's no way to do this without impacting the css of the unvisited links (I tried replacing your blue with transparent, but it breaks the other rule) ?

Comment: Correct. `:visited` can't change the thickness, transparency, or existence of the border. But you *can* set the unvisited link's border color to the same color as the background, EG white for many pages.

Answer (score 0):

That's what `a:visited`in the CSS is for.

```
a:visited {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #09d;
}
```

In case of an image inside the `<a>` tag you could for example do this:

```
a:visited {
  border: 1px dotted green;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't seem to work. text-decoration and color are only for texts, not images, and the border option does not seem to be applicable for security reasons

Comment: security reasons? I doubt that, a border can't do any harm... But you might try to add `!important`, like this: `a:visited {  border: 1px dotted green !important; }`

Comment: oopps, I just saw that `greasemonkey` tag now. So you are not writing code yourself, I assume. I have to admit I don't know Greasemonkey, the above answer was given with changing the original code in mind...