# Force Users to Click <a> Links In Sequential <ol> <li> Order

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, anchor

I have a order list with about 10 list items that have anchor tag links associated with them. I am trying to force the user to only be able to click the child of the parent li once the link is visited. So in a sense I want to force the user to click the li links in the sequential order that is generated by the ol.

Here is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>titlePage</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="titlePage.css"></head>
  <script src="../jsLibraries/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="titlePage.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<img id="backgroundIMG" src="images/Chapter-v2.png">

<ol id="chapterNumbers">
   <li><a href="../chapters/chapter0.html">Chapter 0 - Animate Content</a></li>
  <li><a href="../chapters/chapter1.html">Chapter 1 - Animate Content 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="../chapters/chapter2.html">Chapter 2 - Video Content</a></li>
  <li><a href="../chapters/chapter3.html">Chapter 3 - Video Content 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="../chapters/chapter4.html">Chapter 4 - Audio Content</a></li>
  <li><a href="../chapters/chapter5.html">Chapter 5 - Blah</a></li>
  <li><a href="../chapters/chapter6.html">Chapter 6 - Blah</a></li>
  <li><a href="../chapters/chapter7.html">Chapter 7 - Blah</a></li>
  <li><a href="../chapters/chapter8.html">Chapter 8 - Blah</a></li>
  <li><a href="../chapters/exam.html">Exam</a></li>
</ol>

<header id="courseTitle"> 001234OOELNA - Example Course Using Adobe Animate </header>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my jQuery JS that I was starting with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("li").first().nextAll().click(function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

Here is the CSS associated with the anchor tag being visited:

```
a:visited {
color:white;
}
```

Here is a link to the out put as it is:

http://skywest.theyard.space/index/titlePage.html

Can anyone please help me figure out where I'm going wrong and how to make it so once that first link is clicked the first-child's link is activated (returned true?) and so on so the user has to click the links in sequential order?

Thank you!
Eric

Comment: FYI, you cannot target `:visited` pseudo selector in javascript for obvious security reason. Now if you just want user to click in sequential order per page load, this is of course possible

Comment: whats the problem with only showing "available" links on each page (ie page 1 only show page 1 link, page 2 show page 1,2 links)?

Comment: So once they click the first link, **then** they can click the second link and so on and so forth? Can they click the same link more than once?

Comment: _"So in a sense I want to force the user to click the li links in the sequential order that is generated by the ol"_ Not entirely sure what expected result is? User must click `<a>` in sequential order? User must click first `<a>` first? Then, only second `<a>` can be clicked?

Comment: So how do you know when the next link should be clickable? What happens when they refresh the page?

Comment: @epascarello Should be possible using `history` or `localStorage`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload/30144363?s=2|1.3555#30144363

Comment: Why have navigation in the page if the user isn't going to be allowed to click on it?  Just omit the extra links from each page.

Comment: @JefréN. Yes this is exactly what I'm looking for. Yes they can click the link more than once. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @SamuelCook because it's like the table of contents in a book.

Comment: You already accepted an answer ... Confused. Why do you want to know if I can do it?

Comment: Sorry man. Was working top to bottom and didn't see the answer until after I replied to you. Thank you for your help! @JefréN.

Comment: Ok. No problem. Glad you got your problem solved.

Comment: Well I'm still having problems figuring out how to be able to click the link more than once. As you can see in the thread below with the answer I marked correct. localStorage doesn't seem to be solving the issue right now for some reason... @JefréN.

Comment: Is it supposed to save what links can be clicked between page loads?

Comment: Yea. For example. User goes to titlePage. Initially only chapter 0 link is enabled. User clicks chapter 0 and goes through pages until returns to titlePage. At that point since chapter 0 has been visited. Chapter 0 and Chapter 1 are now enabled. User clicks Chapter 1 and goes through until returning to titlePage. Now Chapter 0, Chapter 1, and Chapter2 are enabled. And so on...User can click any of the previous chapters that they have visited to review if they desire...Does this make sense? @JefréN.

Comment: Yea, it does. mile

Comment: There. I gave you an answer with error checking and all the goodies... Please Upvote if it's useful ... Ask if you don't understand. Thanks. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If user click on link, is navigated out of links page, so any trick
with add/remove class will not work.

So this code is supposed to work even after return to page with links.
And order is reseted after closing/opening browser.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  if (!sessionStorage.active) {
    sessionStorage.active = "1";
  }

  (function set() {
    $("li a").each(function(idx, elm) {
      if (sessionStorage.active != idx+1) {
        $(elm)
          .parent().fadeTo(1, 0.7)
          .off("click").on("click", function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
          });
      } else {
        $(elm)
          .parent().fadeTo(500, 1)
          .off("click").on("click", function() {
            sessionStorage.active = parseInt(sessionStorage.active, 10) + 1;
            set();
          });
      }
    });
  }());
});
```

Version 2:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  if (!localStorage.active) {
    localStorage.active = "1";
  }

  (function set() {
    $("li a").each(function(idx, elm) {
      if (localStorage.active < idx+1) {
        $(elm)
          .parent().fadeTo(1, 0.7)
          .off("click").on("click", function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
          });
      } else if (localStorage.active == idx+1){
        $(elm)
          .parent().fadeTo(1000, 1)
          .off("click").on("click", function() {
            localStorage.active = parseInt(localStorage.active, 10) + 1;
            set();
          });
      } else if (localStorage.active > idx+1) {
        $(elm)
          .parent().fadeTo(1000, 1)
          .off("click").on("click", function() {
            return true;
          });
      } 
    });
  }());
});
```

Or Version 2 hyper "smplfd", partly inspired by jefré-n code

```
$(function(){var a=localStorage.a||0,l=$('a')
l.click(function(){if(l.index(this)>a)return false
if(l.index(this)==a)localStorage.a=++a})})
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep the ones that have been visited still able to be visited a second time? Sorry I didn't make that original comment clear enough...

Comment: Yes, it is. Just use localStorage instead of sessionStorage.

Comment: So are you saying just change the words sessionStorage to localStorage? I tried that and it still doesn't seem to be allowing me to visit a link twice. Once it moves on I can not click on a link I previously visited...Any idea why? You're a big help I appreciate this a lot!

Comment: I might not have been clear - By second time I meant if they want to review a link's content that they have already visited... For example. User goes to titlePage. Initially only chapter 0 link is enabled. User clicks chapter 0 and goes through pages until returns to titlePage. At that point since chapter 0 has been visited. Chapter 0 and Chapter 1 are now enabled. User clicks Chapter 1 and goes through until returning to titlePage. Now Chapter 0, Chapter 1, and Chapter2 are enabled. And so on...User can click any of the previous chapters that they have visited to review if they desire.

Comment: Ok. I added Version 2. I hope its what you want.

Comment: Sorry - I realized I don't have access to the server and my documents until after the Labor Day holiday. I'll get back to you on Tuesday about this. Hope that's ok? Thank you! Your help is appreciated so much!

Comment: I appreciate the "partly inspired" part. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's appreciated a lot! Both you and @JefréN. have been a huge help!

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. (I comment my code well so an explanation shouldn't be necessary. If, however, you need clarification, just tell me... :D)

```
var $links = $("li a");

//simplify localStorage error checking
var supportsLS = true;
try {
    //this will throw an exception if we can't use localStorage
    //ie. the user, like me, disables cookies ... :)
    localStorage.supportsLocalStorage = true;
    }
catch (exc) {
    supportsLS = false;
    }

//initialize the first link they can use
if (supportsLS && localStorage.getItem("nextAvail") === null) {
    localStorage.nextAvail = 0;
    }

function onLinkClick (evt) {
    /*
    This handles a given click on a link.
    */

    //no point in running rest of code--they don't have localStorage support
    //OR we aren't allowed to use it
    if (supportsLS === false) {
        return;
        }

    //cache some info -- improve readability
    var thisInd = $links.index(this);
    var nextAvail = parseInt(localStorage.nextAvail);

    //they can't view this link -- prevent it from working
    if (thisInd > nextAvail) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        }

    //if they clicked the last link they're allowed to click,
    //update localStorage.nextAvail so they can click the next link.
    else if (thisInd === nextAvail) {
        localStorage.nextAvail = thisInd + 1;
        }
    }

//setup onclick handlers
$links.click(onLinkClick);
```

---

**Summary of what was wrong:**

The way I originally handled "*updating*" `localStorage.nextAvail` was <del>flawed</del> **plain** wrong. You can check the code to see why, but suffice it to say that the "*updating*" updated nothing, and while using the program in the intended way, the user could accidentally undo their progress.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! I'm going to test this when I get home from this flight and get back to you :)

Comment: Sorry - I realized I don't have access to the server and my documents until after the Labor Day holiday. I'll get back to you on Tuesday about this. Hope that's ok? Thank you! Your help is appreciated so much!

Comment: @EricBelisleGiddings: No problem. :)

Comment: @EricBelisleGiddings: I'm looking forward to you testing my answer tomorrow... :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be letting me past the first link. 1-9 are locked down but don't open up sequentially once the first link is visited. I'm guessing it's a small fix since WaldemarIce was inspired by your code ;) Or maybe I'm doing something wrong implementing it? I have it inside a $(document).ready( function() {});

Comment: @EricBelisleGiddings: Hmmm. Let me check it out. :(

Comment: Ok that's cool. I'm here all day. Let me know if you need any of my help doing anything...

Comment: @EricBelisleGiddings: Sorry about that. It should work now. :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! You're awesome! The commenting is very helpful too! Can I not mark both your answers correct?

Comment: @EricBelisleGiddings: I'm afraid not. However, you can upvote both of our answers. *(I think you already did, though.)* In truth, I think Walder@ probably deserves to be accepted since he gave you a *(semi)* working answer, first. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your JS makes all links but the first non-clickable, regardless of the the fact they have been visited or not.

Unfortunately, you can not determine if a link was visited, based on js (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7291538/3463640)).

Comment: _"Unfortunately, you can not determine if a link was visited"_ Should be possible using `javascript`