# How to count specific visited url?

Tags: html

There are few links and how can we count the number of times these links are visited?

For example :

```
www.example.com?eventname=event A    
www.example.com?eventname=event B
```

Now how to count both visited links and not count the link `www.example.com`.
It should count only above two links.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please submit your code where you count the visit

Comment: This question is repeated. Check the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290959/how-can-i-detect-visited-and-unvisited-links-on-a-page

Comment: i have no code for visit  counte. i am beginner i don't know how it is possible

Comment: Add an on click method to the a tag and when the user clicks the links it will run a script in the script you can increment the counter.

Comment: thanks Arey. but this link when open it will automatic the count.not on click

Comment: @DipakParmar I don't understand what do you mean by open ? when it get clicked the link opens. Do you mean when the target page loads?

Comment: @Arey  You are right when target page open or load one count lead

Answer (score 1):

In the target page add these lines of code

```
   <script> 
    function count()
    {
    // do counting here 
    }

</script>
    <body onload="count()">
```

I would suggest you to expand your knowledge and try learning JavaScript and its libraries.