# SCSS making visited link not clickable not working

Tags: css, hyperlink

I want it such that an `a` element that is visited and of the class, `myclass` is `lightgreen` and not clickable. I am able to make it `lightgreen`, but it is still clickable.

My code:

```css
a:visited.upvote {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  color: lightgreen;
}
```

and when that code is applied to all `a` elements, regardless of class and visited status (`a {...}`), the link is disabled as it should be.

Comment: Can you please share your html?

Comment: @DanielA.White its just `<a href="...">link</a>`

Comment: Your HTML indicates that the target element does not have the `upvote` class, so the CSS will not apply to it.

Comment: @ObsidianAge oops, meant to indicate 'upvote' in the question

Answer (score 1):

The `pointer-events` property can't be applied to the `:visited` CSS pseudo-class due to:

### **Privacy restrictions**

> Because of privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit which
> styles you can apply using this pseudo-class, and how they can be
> used:
>
> - Allowable CSS properties are `color`, `background-color`, `border-color`,    `border-bottom-color`, `border-left-color`,
>   `border-right-color`,    `border-top-color`, `column-rule-color`,
>   `outline-color`,    `text-decoration-color`, and
>   `text-emphasis-color`.

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited).

A workaround would be adding a click event listener to the tags and then add to it a class that would apply the `pointer-events: none;` like so:

```js
const unclickable = document.getElementById("unclickable")

unclickable.addEventListener("click", makeitso)

function makeitso() {
  unclickable.className = "notSoClickableLink"
}
```

```css
div{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.notSoClickableLink{
  pointer-events: none;
  color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">The first Link</a>
  <a id="unclickable" href="#2">Make this a visited Link</a>
</div>
```

This solution would not track your link tag's state, to circumvent that you can try referring to this post: [How can I detect visited and unvisited links on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290959/how-can-i-detect-visited-and-unvisited-links-on-a-page)