# Inserting a html attribute to visited links on Chrome?

Tags: javascript

There's a way to apply CSS to `a` html tags where its link is a visited URL on the Chrome browser. It's a pseudo CSS `:visited`.

```
a:visited{
   color: red !important;
}
```

What I want to do is to check if the `a` tag is a visited one or not, aka it has `:visited` or not.

I need this because later I can use that information for Tampermonkey or uBlock, so I need to be able to identity which `a` tags are visited or not through its html.

So, is it possible to make the html like this below with a JS?

```
// from this
<a target="_blank">a boring page I haven't visited yet</a>
<a target="_blank">an interesting page I already visited</a>
```

```
// to this
<a target="_blank">a boring page I haven't visited yet</a>
<a target="_blank visited">an interesting page I already visited</a>
```

Comment: Mybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290959/how-can-i-detect-visited-and-unvisited-links-on-a-page